# switch case gets called twice

Tags: php, switch-statement, fread

My php script is supposed to simply take a filename and within a specific directory outputs the filename's contents. The issue is that it does that BUT it apparently once again calls the case resulting in throwing errors, I have tried to replace switch with if/else but still it recalls itself(The code related to case:"1"). Here are the error:

```
    Warning: fopen(C:/xampp/htdocs/phptut/practice/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptut\practice\fileuploadread.php on line 8

    Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptut\practice\fileuploadread.php on line 9

    Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptut\practice\fileuploadread.php on line 10
```

And This is the code:

```
    switch($_GET['id']){
        case"1":

            {   //here $file gets the pathtothefile + filename
                $file="C:/xampp/htdocs/phptut/practice/" . $_POST["element"];
                $fh=fopen($file,"r");
                $contents=fread($fh,filesize($file));
                fclose($fh);
                   //It does output the $contents at this point
                echo $contents;

            }
            break;
        default:{

            echo"
                <html>
                        <head>
                            <style type='text/css'>
                                fieldset{
                                    background-color:lightblue;
                                    border-color:blue;
                                    width:50%;
                                    margin-left:auto;
                                    margin-right:auto;
                                    margin-top:200px;

                                }
                                legend{
                                    color:blue;

                                }
                            </style>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend> Upload Your CV </legend>
                                <form method='POST' name='form' action='fileuploadread.php?id=1'>
                                    <input type='input' name='element' size='20' /><br/>
                                    <input type='submit' value='submit...'/>
                                </form>
                            </fieldset> 
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    ";
    }       }
    ?>
```

Comment: It looks to me like your code is working but you haven't included error handling.

Comment: "apparently" ...well, I'm afraid to say "apparently not".

Comment: Can you provide the code around your switch case?

Comment: @tonymarschall This is all the code, the php file will either show the form or run the script depending on the value of the $_GET['id']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what real problem is here, but you should check file pointer is good before using it in fread() and fclose() calls

```
$fh=fopen($file,"r");
if ($fh) {
   $contents=fread($fh,filesize($file));
   fclose($fh);
}
```

If there is a chance the file does not exist, then check first and deal with it.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
   // do something with file
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: Well when i specify the filename ("element" in the code) the script actually outputs it's contents. After that it reloads and outputs the errors. My guess is that case"1": is being called twice I don't know why thought, i never call it twice in the code... Since it doesn't get a file the second time it throws errors

Comment: I just implemented your suggestions, It once again will output the file contents and reload again to throw the same error as if no file has been passed.

Comment: Ok i just found out what the problem was. The file that i was trying to open contained some HTML code where the variable within the meta tag was set to refresh every 2 seconds, thats why it was recalling the script with no file! Thank you for the valuable code regarding validation though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out:

1. in `$file` you hard-code the paths with forward slashes, but your Windows system uses backslashes - you'd be better querying the system's native file path;
2. `switch` is usually used for multiple options - you only have one and a default? You could try a simple `if`-`else` in a function instead and see if the duplication still occurs.

...and as Adam says, add a little error-checking.